# how to find out the name of a grid?

Tags: dynamics-crm

i just want to find out the name of this grid to refresh it.

E.g.: document.getElementById("**GridName?**").control.refresh();

any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit F12 in IE, and use the pointer to point at the grid in question.  The source view will containt the id somewhere.